# How to write a function that connects each previous word to the next word by the shared letters

Tags: ruby

Return the resulting string (removing duplicate characters in the overlap) and the minimum number of shared letters across all pairs of strings.
Examples

```
join(["oven", "envier", "erase", "serious"]) ➞ ["ovenvieraserious", 2]
join(["move", "over", "very"]) ➞ ["movery", 3]
join(["to", "ops", "psy", "syllable"]) ➞ ["topsyllable", 1]

# "to" and "ops" share "o" (1)
# "ops" and "psy" share "ps" (2)
# "psy" and "syllable" share "sy" (2)
# the minimum overlap is 1
```

join(["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"]) ➞ ["aaabbbcccddd", 0]
Notes
More specifically, look at the overlap between the previous words ending letters and the next word's beginning letters.

Comment: From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): _"Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."_

Comment: OK @CarySwoveland

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Code**

```
def doit(arr)
  a, nbr = arr.each_cons(2).map do |s1,s2|
    n = [s1.size, s2.size].min.downto(1).find { |n| s1[-n..-1] == s2[0,n] }
    n.nil? ? [s2, 0] : [s2[n..-1],n]
  end.transpose
  [a.unshift(arr.first).join, nbr.min]
end
```

**Examples**

```
doit ["oven", "envier", "erase", "serious"]
    #=> ["ovenvieraserious", 2] 
doit ["move", "over", "very"]
    # ["movery", 3]
doit ["to", "ops", "psy", "syllable"]
    #["topsyllable", 1]
```

**Explanation**

The steps are as follows.

```
arr = ["oven", "envier", "erase", "serious"]

e = arr.each_cons(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["oven", "envier", "erase", "serious"]:each_cons(2)>
```

see [Enumerable#each_cons](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons). We can see the elements that will be generated by this enumerator and passed to `map` by converting it to an array.

```
e.to_a
  #=> [["oven", "envier"], ["envier", "erase"], ["erase", "serious"]]
```

Continuing,

```
b = e.map do |s1,s2|
  n = [s1.size, s2.size].min.downto(1).find {|n| s1[-n..-1] == s2[0,n]}
  n.nil? ? [s2, 0] : [s2[n..-1],n]
end
  #=> [["vier", 2], ["ase", 2], ["rious", 2]]
a, nbr = b.transpose
  #=> [["vier", "ase", "rious"], [2, 2, 2]] 
a #=> ["vier", "ase", "rious"] 
nbr
  #=> [2, 2, 2]
```

Computing `a` and `nbr` from `b.transpose` makes use of
[Array Decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition). Continuing,

```
c = a.unshift(arr.first)
  #=> ["oven", "vier", "ase", "rious"] 
d = c.join
  #=> "ovenvieraserious" 
e = nbr.min
  #=> 2 
[d, e]
  #=> ["ovenvieraserious", 2]
```

Consider now the calculation of `b`. The first element is generated by `e` and passed to `map`, which passes it to its block, and values are assigned to the block variables (again, with the help of array decomposition).

```
s1, s2 = e.next
  #=> ["oven", "envier"]
s1
  #=> "oven"
s2
  #=> "envied"
```

The block calculation is now performed.

```
f = [s1.size, s2.size].min
  #=> [4,6].min
  #=> 4
g = f.downto(1).find { |n| s1[-n..-1] == s2[0,n] }
  #=> 2
```

In computing `g` the block calculation preceeds as follows.

```
 n = 4
 s1[-n..-1] == s2[0,n]
   #=> "oven" == "envi" => false

 n = 3
 s1[-n..-1] == s2[0,n]
   #=> "ven" == "env" => false

 n = 2
 s1[-n..-1] == s2[0,n]
   #=> "en" == "en" => true
```

This means that, when `n #=> 2`, the string consisting of the last `n` characters of `s1` equals the first `n` characters of `s2`, and that is the largest value of `n` having that property.

Then

```
 n.nil? ? [s2, 0] : [s2[n..-1],n]
   #=> [s2[n..-1],n]
   #=> ["envied"[2..-1],2]
   #=> ["vied",2]
```

The next value of `e` is then generated, passed to `map` and the block variables are assigned new values:

```
s1, s2 = e.next
  #=> ["oven", "envier"]
```

The block calculation is then performed, and so on.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution in js.

```js
function joinOverlapping(words) {
    function joinWords(word1, word2) {
        let result = "";

        let j = 0;
        for(let i=0; i<word1.length; i++) {
            if(word1[i] != word2[j]) {
                result += word1[i];
            }else {
                result += word1[i];
                j += 1;
            }
        }
        
        result += word2.substring(j);
        return result;
    }

    //forward
    let joined_f = words[0];
    for(let i=1; i<words.length; i++) {
        joined_f = joinWords(joined_f, words[i]);
    }


    return joined_f;
    
}
```